# Two Modules, both exporting the same name

Tags: module, package, julia

There are two packages I want to use: [CorpusLoaders.jl](https://github.com/oxinabox/CorpusLoaders.jl/), and [WordNet.jl](https://github.com/jbn/WordNet.jl)

- CorpusLoaders.SemCor exports `sensekey(::SenseTaggedWord)`
- WordNet exports `sensekey(::DB, ::Synset, ::Lemma)`

I want to use both `sensekey` methods.

Eg

for some mixed list of items: `mixedlist::Vector{Union{Tuple{SenseTaggedWord},Tuple{DB, Synset,Lemma}}`.
Ie the items in the list are a mixture of 1-tuples of `SenseTaggedWord`, and3 tuples of `DB`, `Synset`, and `Lemma`.

```
for item in mixedlist
    println(sensekey(item...)
end
```

should work.
This example is a little facetious, since why would I be mixing them like this.
But, hopefully it serves for illustrating the problem in the general case.

Trying to `using CorpusLoaders.SemCor, WordNet` to bring in both results in `WARNING: both WordNet and Semcor export "sensekey"; uses of it in module Main must be qualified.`

Manually importing both: `import CorpusLoaders.SemCor.sensekey; import WordNet.sensekey`  results in `WARNING: ignoring conflicting import of Semcor.sensekey into Main`

**What can be done? I want them both, and they don't really conflict, due to multiple-dispatch.**

---

Given that CorpusLoaders.jl is a package I am writing I do have a few more options, since I could make my CorpusLoaders.jl depend on WordNet.jl.
If I did do than then I could say in CorpusLoaders.jl

```
 import WordNet
 function WordNet.sensekey(s::SenseTaggedWord)...
```

and that would make them both work.
But it would mean requiring WordNet as a dependency of CorpusLoaders.

And I want to know how to solve the problem for a consumer of the packages -- not as the creator of the packages.

Comment: nah, leave it, my answer is mostly about the user case anyway. hopefully someone with the same question who needs a bit (or a *lot* :p ) more detail than FengYang's answer will bump into mine below next :D  I just wanted to move my comments into an answer to remove them from here, heheh. I'll delete the torrent of comments above now :p
Thanks for taking the time to edit / clarify!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, the functions do not conflict, but in general that is impossible to guarantee. It could be the case that a package loaded later will add methods to one of the functions that will conflict. So to be able to use the `sensekey` for both packages requires some additional guarantees and restrictions.

One way to do this is to ignore both package's `sensekey`, and instead provide your own, dispatching to the correct package:

```
sensekey(x) = CorpusLoaders.sensekey(x)
sensekey(x, y, z) = WordNet.sensekey(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 9):

**tl;dr** qualify the functions when using them in your script via their module namespace, i.e. `CorpusLoader.sensekey()` and `WordNet.sensekey()`

---

**Explanation**

My understanding of your question after the edits (thank you for clarifying) is that:

- You have written a package called `CorpusLoaders.jl`, which exports the function `sensekey(::SenseTaggedWord)`
- There is an external package called `WordNet.jl`, which exports the function `sensekey(::DB, ::Synset, ::Lemma)`
- You have a script that makes use of both modules.

and you are worried that `using` the modules or "importing" the functions directly could potentially create ambiguity and / or errors in your script, asking

1. how can I write my `CorpusLoaders` package to prevent potential clashes with other packages, and
2. how can I write my script to clearly disambiguate between the two functions while still allowing their use?

I think this stems from a slight confusion how `using` and `import` are different from each other, and how modules create a namespace. This is very nicely explained in the docs [here](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/modules/#summary-of-module-usage).

In essence, the answers are:

1. You should not worry about exporting things from your module that will clash with other modules. This is what modules are for: you're creating a namespace, which will "qualify" all exported variables, e.g. `CorpusLoaders.sensekey(::SenseTaggedWord)`.
2. When you type `using CorpusLoaders`, what you're saying to julia is "import the module itself, *and* all the exported variables stripped from their namespace qualifier, and bring them into Main". Note that this means you now have access to `sensekey` as a function directly from Main without a namespace qualifier, *and* as `CorpusLoaders.sensekey()`, since you've also imported the *module* as a variable you can use.

If you then try `using` the module `WordNet` as well, julia very reasonably issues a warning, which essentially says:

> "You've imported two functions that have the same name. I can't just strip their namespace off because that could create problems in some scenarios (even though in your case it wouldn't because they have different signatures, but I couldn't possibly know this in general). If you want to use either of these functions, please do so using their appropriate namespace qualifier".

So, the solution for 2. is:

- you either do

  ```
  using CorpusLoaders;
  using WordNet;
  ```

  , disregarding the warning, to import all other exported variables as usual in your Main namespace, and access those particular functions directly via their modules as `CorpusLoaders.sensekey()` and `WordNet.sensekey()` each time you need to use them in your script, or
- you keep both modules clearly disambiguated at all times by doing

  ```
  import CorpusLoaders;
  import WordNet;
  ```

  and qualify *all* variables appropriately, or
- in this particular case where the function signatures don't clash, if you'd *really* like to be able to use the function without a namespace qualifier, relying on multiple dispatch instead, you can do something like what FengYang suggested:

  ```
   import CorpusLoaders;
   import WordNet;
   sensekey(a::SenseTaggedWord) = CorpusLoader.sensekey(a);
   sensekey(a::DB, b::Synset, c::Lemma) = WordNet.sensekey(a, b, c);
  ```

  which is essentially a ***new*** function, defined on module Main, acting as a wrapper for the two namespace-qualified functions.

In the end, it all comes down to using `using` vs `import` and namespaces appropriately for your particular code. :)

---

As an addendum, code can get very unwieldy with long namespace qualifiers like `CorpusLoader` and `WordNet`. julia doesn't have something like python's `import numpy as np`, *but* at the same time modules become simple variables on your workspace, so it's trivial to create an alias for them. So you can do:

```
import CorpusLoaders; const cl = CorpusLoaders;
import Wordnet;       const wn = WordNet;
# ... code using both cl.sensekey() and wn.sensekey()
```

Answer (score 6):

I implemented what @Fengyang Wang said,
as a function:

```
function importfrom(moduleinstance::Module, functionname::Symbol, argtypes::Tuple)
    meths = methods(moduleinstance.(functionname), argtypes)
    importfrom(moduleinstance, functionname, meths)
end 

function importfrom(moduleinstance::Module, functionname::Symbol)
    meths = methods(moduleinstance.(functionname))
    importfrom(moduleinstance, functionname, meths)
end 

function importfrom(moduleinstance::Module, functionname::Symbol, meths::Base.MethodList)
    for mt in meths
        paramnames = collect(mt.lambda_template.slotnames[2:end])
        paramtypes = collect(mt.sig.parameters[2:end])
        paramsig = ((n,t)->Expr(:(::),n,t)).(paramnames, paramtypes)

        funcdec = Expr(:(=), 
                        Expr(:call, functionname, paramsig...),
                        Expr(:call, :($moduleinstance.$functionname), paramnames...)
        )
        current_module().eval(funcdec) #Runs at global scope, from calling module

    end
end
```

Call with:

```
using WordNet
using CorpusLoaders.Semcor

importfrom(CorpusLoaders.Semcor, :sensekey)
importfrom(WordNet, :sensekey)

methods(sensekey)
```

**2 methods for generic function sensekey:**

- sensekey(db::WordNet.DB, ss::WordNet.Synset, lem::WordNet.Lemma)
- sensekey(saword::CorpusLoaders.Semcor.SenseAnnotatedWord

If you wanted to get really flash you could reexport the DocString too.