# Julia: Strange error when comparing strings: "no method matching ==(::String, ::String)"?

Tags: string, julia, string-comparison

I have some code that I wrote back when Julia was in version 0.4, and now I have version 0.5.0

However, when I try to run the old code (after fixing some other issues), now I get the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching ==(::String, ::String)
you may have intended to import Base.==
```

Which seems rather strange. The error occurs on the following line:

```
if fname == "run"
```

where

```
fname = convert(String, params[1])
```

and

```
params = split(readline()[1:end - 1])
```

Comment: can you make a few lines of code that make a reproducible example (i.e. that anyone can run to reproduce the error)

Answer (score 1):

The little code that you supplied works fine for me:

```
julia> params = split(readline()[1:end - 1])
run this thing
3-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "run"
 "this"
 "thing"

julia> fname = convert(String, params[1])
"run"

julia> if fname == "run"
           println("success")
       else
           println("failure")
       end
success
```

The problem may be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was a custom definition for the == function.
Although I don't know why it broke it, as it's definition began with:

```
function ==(a::Move, b::Move)
```

Regardless, removing that function and making the Move type immutable fixed the problem.

Comment: The error message you reported above tells you what happened. You must now do import Base.== before you overload this function.

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders Thanks. That makes sense, except that I don't see why Julia will let me use == before importing it, isn't the default == the one that I would import from Base?

Comment: Once you use `==`, Julia "knows" that `==` refers to `Base.==`. But it also allows you to define your own, completely independent `==` function, as long as you do so *before* you use `Base.==`.

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders Doesn't Julia use multiple dispatch though? So if I write == and Julia can't find a definition in my code, shouldn't it know to look into the other modules that have been imported, and find the proper == from Base?

Comment: Kytuzian: the multiple dispatch occurs at a different level to what you may think. (Some of the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554601/t) might give good background).
Basically: each module has at most 1 function with a given name, and that function may have multiple methods. If I have a funtion `foo` in some module `ModA` (eg `Base`) and another function `foo` in some other module `ModB` (eg `Main`). Then the collection of methods for `ModA.foo` and for `ModB.foo` do not interact and do not share dispatch. They are different functions.