# namespace clashes in Julia

Tags: namespaces, julia

When I get libraries with the `using` keyword I get warnings in the console on startup. How can I mitigate the problem of name clashes? I don't see library alias keyword `as` which is available in other programming languages.

Comment: You can use `import` instead.

Comment: Can I `use` part of the whole package?

Comment: For reference, which libraries?

Comment: see [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39566646/4183191) it covers all the important issues related to your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `import` instead. You can always alias it yourself since modules are just variables:

```
import DifferentialEquations
DiffEq = DifferentialEquations
const DE = DifferentialEquations # Don't know if const matters here
```

There's an open issue for providing `import as` syntactic sugar for this. https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1255

Comment: You should always do `const`! If not then `DiffEq.foo`, and any calls to it, will never be inferable.

Comment: Wasn't sure if modules had an implicit const or something in it.