# Overloading function names already in use by imported modules

Tags: julia

I want to define a function

```
function f(a :: my_type, b :: other_args)
    ...
end
```

However, I am already using a module `other_module` which has already defined `f(a :: other_module_type, b :: other_args)`. As a consequence (and apparently only if I've already used `f(a :: other_module_type ...)`), when I define my function I get the error:

```
ERROR: error in method definition: function other_module.f must be explicitly imported to be extended
```

I don't see why it is necessary to extend another module just because my function shares the same name. What logic stops me from defining my own version of `f(...)`, and how can I avoid linking otherwise independent pieces of code as I would by extending `other_module.f`?

An example:

```
 using Dierckx
 a = Spline1D([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4])
 derivative(a, 1.0)
 type b end
 function derivative(c::b, x)
     return x
 end

 ERROR: error in method definition: function Dierckx.derivative must be explicitly imported to be extended
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/39566646/4183191

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `import` the module rather than `using` it, so that the names defined there won't go into your scope. The consequence is that you need to specify the module name to explicitly call functions inside the module.

For example, your code should be like this:

```
import Dierckx
a = Dierckx.Spline1D([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4])
Dierckx.derivative(a, 1.0)
type b end
function derivative(c::b, x)
    return x
end

// now derivative() is your function, and Dierckx.derivative() calls the one in the module
```

The mechanism behinds is that Julia functions can contain multiple methods with different signatures ([the doc](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/methods/)), so defining a function with the same name of existing ones is essentially extending them. To prevent accidentally extending irrelevant functions, functions need to be explicitly imported (like `import Dierckx.derivative`) to extend, otherwise the error occurs as you see.

For the difference of `import` and `using`, see [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/modules/#modules-1).