# Import modules and functions from a file in a specific directory in Julia 1.0

Tags: import, julia, using

Let's say I had a file `File.jl` that had a module `MyModule` containing the functions `foo` and `bar` in it. In the same directory as the module-file, I had a script `Script.jl`, and I wanted to use the functions in `MyModule` in the script.

How would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find Modules that are not in the standard LOAD_PATH and be able to import them, you need to update your LOAD_PATH variable for the current folder explicitly

```
push!( LOAD_PATH, "./" )
```

then you will be able to import a module appropriately.

Note that, if the file is called `File.jl` and defines the module `MyModule`, what you should be importing is `import MyModule`, not `import File`. It is generally recommended you use the same name for the file as for the defined module in this kind of scenario, to avoid confusion.

Also note, As @crstnbr noted above, you can also simply 'dump' the file's contents into the current session by simply 'including' it; note however that this simply creates the module on the spot, so any precompilation directives etc will not be honoured.

---

Somewhat related questions / answers (disclaimer: by me) you might find useful:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50627721/4183191
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49405645/4183191

Comment: Can the push!-function be run from within the script in a way that the change in the LOAD_PATH doesn't become permanent?

Comment: Regardless, this seems to have solved the import issue, but now I receive the following error message: `LoadError: importing MyModule into Main conflicts with an existing identifier`. It's caused by the line that imports the module by calling `using MyModule`.

Comment: Your module seems to be exporting a function that already exists in Main (maybe because another package exports the same function)

Comment: @crstnrb Is this an issue with `using`? Shoud I be using `import` instead, if my module exports anything?

Comment: @TheSodesa yes, just use import and use the exported function qualified by module name. See [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39566646/4183191) on this as well.

Comment: @TheSodesa also, to answer your first question, the LOAD_PATH variable is not saved after you end each session, so it's safe to `push!` stuff to it. If you __did__ want the LOAD_PATH changed permanently, you'd do so by adding such `push!` instructions in your julia initilization script.

Comment: Hi, I wrote `push!( LOAD_PATH, "./" )` but it didn't work. I tried replacing LOAD_PATH with my actual path, and then `"./"` with my actual path, but it still says `SystemError: opening file *x*: Permission denied`. So my questions are, where exactly do I put `push!( LOAD_PATH, "./" )`, how do I specify a path into it, how do I import my module after specifying it? The other answer worked by the way.

Comment: @stunlocked you should be opening a different question for this, but basically you have a permissions error. Nothing to do with the load path. Also, don't "replace" `LOAD_PATH`. `LOAD_PATH` is an internal julia variable which holds directories to be searched when loading modules. What you're doing with the `push!` command here is effectively adding another directory for julia to look into when looking for modules to import. In your case, the directory you're adding has no access permissions from the system (presumably MacOS?). Give permissions to the folder from your Mac shell and it'll work.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou but the other answer works for my directory, I think I am misunderstanding how to use `push!( LOAD_PATH, "./" )`. is that right: `push!( LOAD PATH, "absolute/path/to/my/module")`? And then I can do `import newmodule`? The `"./"` means local directory as far as I understand, why would that be there?

Comment: @stunlocked The "./" was referring to the specific user's question context, who had placed his modules in the same directory as his code. Hence why you should be opening different questions specifying your own context :) The other answer works because they're 'dumping' the definition of the module in their code, as I mentioned in my answer. You are of course free to use this, just keep in mind it will not honour any precompilation directives that way. Also, mind you this answer is 5 years old; in theory it should still be valid, but LOAD_PATH doc has changed and I haven't used julia much since

Comment: @stunlocked but otherwise, yes, that's what it means. Given your primary error is one of "I don't have access permissions to open modules in the folder you specified", I would suggest the following test to see if the method works or not first: copy the modules in the current directory, same as your code, and then try the push! version with the current path. If that works, then this method still works as intended, and the problem is purely one of access permissions in the absolute directory you're trying to access.

Answer (score 3):

You include the file with the module definition and call the functions in your script file:

```
include(joinpath(@__DIR__,"File.jl"))
MyModule.foo()
MyModule.bar()
# or just foor() and bar() if MyModule exports those functions
```

The `@__DIR__` expands to the directory of the script file, see

```
help?> @__DIR__
  @__DIR__ -> AbstractString

  Expand to a string with the absolute path to the directory of the file containing the macrocall. Return the current working directory if run from a REPL or if evaluated by julia -e <expr>.
```

Comment: This worked for me, unlike the other answer. @__DIR__ isn't even necessary if your file is in a different folder