# How to use the module in Julia v0.7

Tags: julia

I have the following set up: `module xxxxx` at the top of my file named xxxxx.jl

I go to do the following:

`include("modules/xxxxx/xxxxx.jl")
using xxxxx`

I get the following error:

ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package xxxxx not found in current path:
- Run `Pkg.add("xxxxx")` to install the xxxxx package.

Any suggestions?  I don't have this error on Julia v0.6 only on v0.7!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write

```
using .xxxxx
```

By using `include` function the module is loaded as a submodule of a current module.
E.g. if you included it in global scope then you can also write

```
using Main.xxxxx
```

But the syntax I gave at the top would work no matter if you are in `Main` module or you include a submodule in another module defined by you.

Comment: Ok, I think that fixed the issue. I am trying to call a function in one of the files I do

Comment: using xxxxx; include("/Users/logankilpatrick/.julia/packages/xxxxx/7IWZq/src/simNomadic.jl"); sim_nomadic()

Comment: I do this in the Julia command line version.  It says that ERROR: UndefVarError: sim_nomadic not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: I looked it up as doing MyModule.nameOfFunction() works!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824403/how-to-import-modules-and-functions-from-a-file-in-a-specific-directory-in-julia

Comment: you can also export `nameOfFunction` from module `xxxxx` and then it will be visible after `using .xxxxx`.